# Sound volume control does not work in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio, osx, pulseaudio

My sound volume control does not work when I'm logged in with my regular user, though the sound works correctly. What's weirder is that the sound control works when I'm logged in as guest.

With my regular user I can't see any output peripherals in `Preferences->Audio` but it will show up when logged in as guest.

The home directory of my regular Ubuntu user is also used as the home directory of my Mac Os X user. Could it be the case there is some kind of conflict? I already tried deleting the `.pulse` directory and `.pulse-cookie` but nothing changed. Only `.pulse-cookie` was recreated when I logged out/logged in.

Do you have any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: What exactly is your "invited session" user? Have you enabled sound permissions for your regular user e.g. added it to the audio group?

Comment: I'm sorry I probably meant guest session. I do belong to the audio group.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could reinstall the ALSA Mixer

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

What also works sometimes is reconfiguring your soundcard in the settings.

```
systemsettings -> sound -> Hardware input/output
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had already tried reinstalling the alsa mixer with no effect. The thing is I actually had nothing showed in Hardware input/output.

Comment: In the end, I moved my home back to /home and I have no more issue. I think it was a bit silly tring to have both mac os x and ubuntu home pointing to the same folder. I had right issues that could explain the sound problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting the sound system:

```
sudo pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa  force-reload
```